# old data removed while try to append new one using CONCAT function in SQL

Tags: sql

I have column called chapters  I store in it the existing chapters like at this format

> Chapter 1 , Chapter  2,  Chapter 3 , ......

but I have problem when I try to append non exist chapter to them I want to append each added chapter in front of the one before it , so if chapter 6 not exist I want it to be between chapter 5 and chapter 7.

I have tried this :

```
def soo(chap_number,id):
        insert_chap = f"""UPDATE crawler SET chapters=
        CONCAT('chapters {chap_number-1},','Chapter {chap_number},') 
        WHERE manga_id = {id};"""
        print(insert_chap)
        cursor.execute(insert_chap)
        data.commit()
```

but I had problem it remove the inserted chapters and leave only added chapters and the one before it

Comment: You have a problem with your DB schema design. Any chance it could be redesigned?

Comment: @Serg this a  wordpress  database may that be the problmem ??

Comment: AFAIK wordpress uses MySql internally and one can create custom MySql tables besides wordpress predefined ones. Looks like `crawler` is a custom table which needs a redesign.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above query is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh i use MySQL , I tried to add chapters in specific position but I found adding it at the end is working too so i have no problem anymore